# iOS Property 'reactDelegate' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate' won't Build

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, appdelegate

Property 'reactDelegate' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *'
[image]

Expo bare workflow project. Not able to get through this issue even after updating the AppDelegate.h file. Any luck here anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to make changes in App Delegate.m changing the following code:
ref: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/15728

````
 RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge moduleName:@"main" initialProperties:nil]; 
 id rootViewBackgroundColor = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"RCTRootViewBackgroundColor"]; 
 if (rootViewBackgroundColor != nil) { 
   rootView.backgroundColor = [RCTConvert UIColor:rootViewBackgroundColor]; 
 } else { 
   rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; 
 } 
  
 self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds]; 
 UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new]; ```
````